# Handling polymorphic value in newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Ok basically I have a problem that I don't konw I can solve (probably was just bad design. but not on my side, if possible I prefer to solve it on my side).

A service I'm using is accepting as JSON parameter a dictionary, where keys are strings, but values can be either numbers or strings:

```
"dictionary":{
    "a": "thisIsA",
    "b":  3,
    "c":  5,
   "key":  "string"
}
```

I need to create a object such that when using newtonsoft for converting it to JSON, it generates the same as above

```
string json = JsonConvert.Serialize(myObject); // here should generate the correct json
```

Comment: Is the sample even a valid JSON format?  Daisy's answer provides a properly formed JSON, but the inclusion of `"dictionary":` is throwing me off.  I know what a `dictionary` is, but this isn't a JSON as provided, no?

Comment: @gravity I imagine OP excluded the enclosing `{ }`, but without confirmation I cant be sure.

Comment: @maccettura True, but I agree, we shouldn't assume.

Comment: Yes I excluded those, the important thing for me was the polymorphic cast. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a `Dictionary<string, object>` will work for that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "a", "thisIsA" },
            { "b", 3 },
            { "c", 5 },
            { "key", "string" }
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "a": "thisIsA",
  "b": 3,
  "c": 5,
  "key": "string"
}
```

That's lacking the `"dictionary":` part, which you'll never get in a "bare" format when serializing an object. But if you put this as part of another object, via a suitable property, it should do what you need.

Comment: @maccettura: It gives them the *value* they want - they'd then serialize it within a "dictionary" property if necessary. I'll add a note to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I'm aware of to generate json like that would be to create a wrapper class around a dictionary that has a dictionary property. Something like this.

```
public class MyDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<string,object> Dictionary{get;}

    public MyDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value){
        Dictionary.Add(key,value);
    }
}
```

then you could use it like this

```
var dictionary = new MyDictionary();
dictionary.Add("a", "thisIsA");
dictionary.Add("b", 3);
dictionary.Add("c", 5);
dictionary.Add("key", "string");
```

and it should serialize out to

```
"dictionary":{
    "a": "thisIsA",
    "b":  3,
    "c":  5,
   "key":  "string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you include in your question is not actually valid JSON.  It can be made valid by enclosing it in `{ }`.  It is not exactly clear from your question, but if you want a *valid* JSON result the simplest way would be to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and an anonymous object when serializing:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "a", "thisIsA" },
    { "b", 3 },
    { "c", 5 },
    { "key", "string" }
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { dictionary });
```

Whatever you name your `Dictionary<string, object>` variable will be the "key" that appears in your json.  So my above code will result in this json:

```
{
    "dictionary":{
        "a": "thisIsA",
        "b":  3,
        "c":  5,
        "key":  "string"
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cREOQY)